# ionic 2 Error 'ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined'

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2, angular-services

I'm been using the ionic 2 [native sqlite plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/) to make a basic app to capture and store images to the phones local storage. I keep getting an uncaught exception error (seemingly from the sql plugin) sometimes when i run the app on the genymotion emulator.

This normally happens when the app reloads when i'm using the -live parameter(ionic run android -c -l). 
I also noticed that data which stored on the app doesn't appear(this again indicates that there is some problem loading the stored data when 'live reloading')
I've put the error i get on the console below:

**The Console error message**

```bash
[13:28:27] Starting 'html'...
[13:28:27] Finished 'html' after 42 ms
HTML changed: www/build/pages/home/home.html
HTML changed: www/build/pages/map-detail-component/map-detail-component.html
HTML changed: www/build/pages/map-page/map-page.html
0     298305   log      Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
1     298474   group    EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined
2     298475   error    EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined
3     298476   error    STACKTRACE:
4     298477   error    Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined
    at resolvePromise (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:418:31)
    at resolvePromise (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:403:17)
    at http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:451:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:225:37)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37360:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:224:42)
    at Zone.runTask (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:125:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:357:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:297:25)
5     298478   groupEnd 
6     298481   error    Unhandled Promise rejection:, sqlitePlugin is not defined, ; Zone:, angular, ; Task:, Promise.then, ; Value:, [object Object], ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined
    at http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:97420:13
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/zone.js:467:29)
    at SQLite.openDatabase (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:97419:16)
    at new SqlService (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:218:21)
    at DebugAppView.Object.defineProperty.get (MyApp.template.js:18:67)
    at DebugAppView._View_MyApp_Host0.injectorGetInternal (MyApp.template.js:35:79)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.injectorGet (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:31753:21)
    at DebugAppView.injectorGet (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:31945:49)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:31246:33)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://192.168.56.1:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:31249:48)
7     298519   log      DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, 1004, ms
8     298609   log      Entering: map-page
9     298620   log      ERROR: , {}
```

This goes away when i restart the emulator but then sometimes appears again after more usage.

I thought this could be due to the SQLite db being created before the plugin is imported but i've imported the plugin in my root app.ts file (shown below) (the whole app can be seen in this [github repo](https://github.com/ah3243/ExampleLocApp))

**Root app.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
    template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
    // Declare services
    providers: [ SqlService ]
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage: any = MapPage;

    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        });
    }
}    
ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

I've confined any use of the plugin to an sqlService (shown below)

**SQL Service**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SQLite} from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class SqlService {
  private db: SQLite;
  private isOpen: boolean;

  public constructor() {
    if(!this.isOpen){
      this.db = new SQLite();
      this.db.openDatabase({
        name: "data.db",
        location: "default"
      }).then(() => {
        this.db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, img TEXT)", []).then((data) => {
          console.log("TABLE CREATED: " + data);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Unable to execute SQL" + error);
        });
        this.isOpen=true;
      });
    }
  }

  public add(title: string, base64Img: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.executeSql("INSERT INTO places (title, img) VALUES ( '"+ title +"', '"+ base64Img +"')", [])
        .then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }

  // Remove individual Location
  public remove(id: number){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.executeSql("DELETE FROM places WHERE id = "+ id +";", [])
        .then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }

  public locDetail(id: number){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM places WHERE id = "+ id +";",[])
        .then((data) => {
          if(data.rows.length===1){
            // console.log("ttitle: " + data.rows.item(0).title + " id: " + data.rows.item(0).id + " img: " + data.rows.item(0).img );
            let place = [];
            place.push({
              id: data.rows.item(0).id,
              title: data.rows.item(0).title,
              img: data.rows.item(0).img
            });
            resolve(place);
          }
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }

  // Refresh and initialise the places object
  public refresh() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM places", []).then((data) => {
          let place = [];
          if (data.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
              place.push({ 
                id: data.rows.item(i).id,
                title: data.rows.item(i).title, 
                img: data.rows.item(i).img 
              });
            }
          }
          resolve(place);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the `SqlStorage` instead. Iv'e been working with it recently and it works fine, while I do remember having problems when I tried to use `SQLite` alone

Comment: ok but doesn't that leave your data open to getting cleaned by the OS if it's stored in webSQL?

Comment: having the same issue in my project. and @MorKadosh, i tried using SqlStorage but getting "has no exported member" error. Yes, i have installed the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin. please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem, make sure you check if the platform is ready also in your service.  Import "Platform" from "ionic-angular" and execute your sqlite interaction code in the promise.then method.

Answer (score 0):

I am using IOS and get the same error `'ReferenceError: sqlitePlugin is not defined'`.

As the sqlite does not work when testing in Chrome browser I tried the `ionic upload` CLI function. Then got the same error.

I came across [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues/52) on Github.

After using `setTimeout` it works in the Ionic view app on IOS:

```
      setTimeout(function() {
          let db = new SQLite();
            db.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)", {}).then((data) => {
                    console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);
                    self.dummy = data
                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("Unable to execute sql", error);
                    self.dummy = error;
                })
            }, (error) => {
                console.error("Unable to open database", error);
                self.dummy = error;
            });
      }, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

please run your projeect in emulator/simulator or android device/ios device.it's not work on browser.

Comment: why won't it work in a browser ? it alwasy used to work in Chrome ?